# How can I create a list of dynamic objects in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, return-by-reference

I have this simple program in C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class test {
    private:
        string _name;
        list<test*> _list;
    public:
        test(const string& S): _name(S) { this->_list.clear(); }

        const string& to_string() {
            string*sp = new string("[");
            *sp += this->_name;
            for(test*tp: this->_list) {
                *sp += ",";
                *sp += tp->to_string();
            }
            *sp += "]";
            return *sp;
        }

        test& add(const string& S) {
            test*tp = new test(S);
            this->_list.push_back(tp);
            return *tp;
        }
};

int main() {
    test x("one");
    x.add("two");
    test y = x.add("three");
    y.add("four");
    cout << y.to_string() << '\n';
    cout << x.to_string() << '\n';
}
```

The idea is to create a list of nested lists. `y` is supposed to be an element of `x`, however when I modify `y`, then `x` is not modified.

The desired output is:

```
[three,[four]]
[one,[two],[three,[four]]]
```

but I get

```
[three,[four]]
[one,[two],[three]]
```

I can probably solve the problem by returning a pointer in `test::add` and modifying `main`:

```cpp
int main() {
    test x("one");
    x.add("two");
    test*p = x.add("three");
    p->add("four");
    cout << y->to_string() << '\n';
    cout << x.to_string() << '\n';
}
```

However. Is there a way to use `y` as type `test` rather than `p` as type `test*`?

Comment: Apart from anything else, why does the copy constructor clear the list?

Comment: I see a lot of (really unnecessary) `new`s, but no `delete`s. If you want `y` to affect `x`, then all you need is a reference, not new objects.

Answer (score 2):

You created a copy of the "three" and added "four" to it.

```
test y = x.add("three");
```

You can do like:

```
test& y = x.add("three");
```

By the way, your code creates memory leaks.  Write virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just make `y` a `test&` to preserve the relationship with `x`:

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/dt6Myn)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using lots of objects dynamically allocated on the heap. Consider using *smart* pointers (like `std::shared_ptr`) instead of raw *owning* pointers, for proper cleanup and to avoid leaks.

I haven't spent much time on this, but taking your initial code and replacing some raw pointer usage with smart pointers (and `std::list` with `std::vector`; unless you do want `list` for its iterator invalidation properties, `std::vector` tends to be a better option), I got this code that seems to work ([**live sample**](https://ideone.com/k9uFfJ)):

**Output:**

> ```
> [three,[four]]
> [one,[two],[three,[four]]]
> ```

**Source:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    string _name;
    vector<shared_ptr<Test>> _list;
public:
    explicit Test(const string& S) : _name(S) { }

    string to_string() const {
        string s("[");
        s += _name;

        for (auto const& p : _list) {
            s += ",";
            s += p->to_string();
        }

        s += "]";
        return s;
    }

    shared_ptr<Test> add(const string& S) {
        auto p = make_shared<Test>(S);
        _list.push_back(p);
        return p;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto x = make_shared<Test>("one");
    x->add("two");
    auto y = x->add("three");
    y->add("four");

    cout << y->to_string() << '\n';
    cout << x->to_string() << '\n';
}
```

As an alternative, if it makes sense for your particular design, you may also consider returning references (`T&`) to your objects from `test::add` instead of (smart) pointers, and use `unique_ptr` (instead of `shared_ptr`) with the `_list` vector data member. This is a kind of alternative version ([**live**](https://ideone.com/vxZ3nU)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    string _name;
    vector<unique_ptr<Test>> _list;
public:
    explicit Test(const string& S) : _name(S) { }

    string to_string() const {
        string s("[");
        s += _name;

        for (auto const& p : _list) {
            s += ",";
            s += p->to_string();
        }

        s += "]";
        return s;
    }

    Test& add(const string& S) {
        _list.push_back(make_unique<Test>(S));
        return *(_list.back());
    }
};

int main() {
    Test x("one");
    x.add("two");
    Test& y = x.add("three");
    y.add("four");

    cout << y.to_string() << '\n';
    cout << x.to_string() << '\n';
}
```